# How to create Community Wiki Questions

Tags: support, questions, community-wiki

For example this one [Code Golf: Seven Segments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1407422/code-golf-seven-segments)

Comment: Does Community Wiki make it magically on topic?

Comment: Help out here: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4570/code-golf-programming-puzzles

Comment: (I actually am not interested in Code Golf. I just knew that I could find an example CW question that way.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't; only moderators can. This was done because some users would erroneously mark their questions as CW without knowing what it's for.

Also, even more people seemed to think that it should be used for off topic questions. This is not true and off topic questions are not allowed, CW or not.

Long story short the vast majority of the users didn't know what it was for or thought they did, so 90%+ of the questions tagged as CW shouldn't have, and now this functionality is mod only.

Comment: [When was the Community Wiki Question capability restricted to moderators only?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74112)

Comment: Stumbled across this, coming from [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5519574/should-startup-ideas-be-tested). I don't know if you or the other high-rank users are aware, but this is still a privilege, defined [here](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/community-wiki). This page might mislead some users now that this feature has been disabled.

Comment: @lunch: you can still mark **answers** as community wiki, and that page specifies "answer"

Comment: Whoops! Nice catch. Thanks for the clarification.