# When was the Community Wiki Question capability restricted to moderators only?

Tags: support, questions, community-wiki

Before, users could mark their own questions as Community Wiki. When was the change that restricted it to moderators?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Why the nonsense in the body?

Comment: To fill the 30 character limit. I edited the question. (using code to fill the limit)

Comment: I answered your question, but I'm still curious why you care.

Comment: @Popular Demand: I was just curious. I saw a 2k reputation user and noticed they had used community wiki on one of their questions and then I just wondered when the change was made.

Comment: Fair enough. (@cjava)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On or about [October 14, 2010](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67039/what-can-we-do-to-make-community-wiki-better/67192#67192).